# ngx-bootstrap: Exclude element in heading from closing an accordion item

Tags: ngx-bootstrap, ng2-bootstrap

Is there a way to exclude a certain element in the `accordion-heading` custom HTML from opening and closing the accordion?

For example,

```
<accordion>
    <accordion-group>
        <div accordion-heading>
            <span>This should close the accordion element (the default behavior)</span>
            <span>This should not close it</span>
        </div>
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it using

`<span (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">This should not close it</span>`

Hopefully will help someone someday!